# How to create date filter filter with bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-3

I want to create a date filter using a bootstrap modal, where when I click submit it will automatically be directed to a new table with the specified date. But my code doesn't work.

this is my modal code:

```
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <a href="#">
        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-3 px-2 mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userReservationModal"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Add Reserve</button>
    </a>
</div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="userReservationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userReservationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="userReservationModalLabel">What's Date You Want Meeting?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url('menu/myReservation'); ?>" method="GET">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Date Start: </label>
                            <input class="form-control date" name="date1" id="date1" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Date End: </label>
                            <input class="form-control date" name="date2" id="date2" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my model:

```
    public function filter($data_filter_start, $data_filter_end)
{

    $result1 = "SELECT*FROM ruang_meeting WHERE created_date >= '$data_filter_start'";
    return $result1;
    $result2 = "SELECT*FROM ruang_meeting WHERE created_date <= '$data_filter_end'";
    return $result2;
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
    $date = $this->input->get('date1');
    $date_month = substr($date, 0, 2);
    $date_day = substr($date, 3, 2);
    $date_year = substr($date, 6, 4);
    $data_filter_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_month, $date_day, $date_year);

    $date2 = $this->input->get('date2');
    $date2_month = substr($date2, 0, 2);
    $date2_day = substr($date2, 3, 2);
    $date2_year = substr($date2, 6, 4);
    $data_filter_end = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date2_month, $date2_day, $date2_year);

    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['nik' =>

    $this->session->userdata('nik')])->row_array();
    $data['reserve'] = $this->Model_reserve->getReserve();
    $data['username'] = $this->Model_reserve->getUser();
    $data['meeting'] = $this->Model_reserve->viewMr();
    $data['filter'] = $this->Model_reserve->filter($data_filter_start, $data_filter_end);
```

Comment: Two return statements in one function are not possible with php. Your `filter` method is faulty. It returns only the `$result1` variable. Even more: Your `filter` function just returns the sql string. What do you expect? Beside that ... what do you mean with `It 's not working`? What do you expect and what do you actually get? This needs a little more description.

Comment: I see, then how do I make two start and end date filters to display the date that matches my chosen bootstrap modals?

My point is, I want to make my bootstrap modals sorted according to the date chosen via modal and then redirected to a database table that has been sorted via modal before. Because the data table is in a different php file.

Comment: First you have to gain basic knowledge about design patterns. A model never reads out data. It just holds data, which was read out before with da database connection in your example. You need a repository or at least an object in your controller, that has a database connection and reads data from a database. The retrieved data can be hydrated in your model.

Comment: Ohh, i see. okay thank you for advice master,

sorry for bad english